# Grating lobe in ULA exhibits a jump

Tags: array-signal-processing

The beam pattern of a uniform linear array is

$$B(\theta) = \frac{1}{N} \frac{\sin(\frac{N}{2} \frac{2\pi d}{\lambda} \cos(\theta))}{\sin(\frac{1}{2} \frac{2\pi d}{\lambda} \cos(\theta))}$$

where $N$ is the number of elements, $d$ the interelement spacing and $\lambda$ the wavelength and $\theta$ the grazing angle.

I was trying to observe the effect of increasing the value of $\frac{d}{\lambda}$ on the beam pattern by plotting the function in MATLAB. It is expected that as $d$ increases, a grating lobe appears in the visible region $-1 \leq u \leq 1$ where $u = \cos(\theta)$.

I did observe grating. However, unlike the plots given in texts (such as the one by Van Trees), the grating lobe exhibits an unusual jump at its maximum. I was wondering if this is ok. If not what needs to be done to correct it? Shown below is the plot.

[image]

Comment: Are you properly handling the 0/0 case?

Comment: If you're up for it, implement the array factor summation directly to avoid this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "bump" at $\cos(\phi) = \pm 0.5,$ (and integer multiples thereof!) and  $d/\lambda = 2$ makes sense, because at that point, the argument to the sine donominator becomes $\pi$, the sine becomes zero, and division by zero diverges. Now, what your numerical program probably doesn't do is the right evaluation of the $B$ function at that these pseudo-singularities: For points where the denominator becomes zero, the function happens to have the limit $1$ (you'll notice L'Hôpital agrees¹). And with that, the function can be analytically continued, the world is good.

So, what needs to be done is a check for denominator being zero, and replacement of the ratio with 1 in that case.

---

¹ if you replace $\cos(\phi)=u$, the derivative of the denominator becomes $\pi/2\cdot \cos(\pi/2 u),$ of the numerator $N\pi/2 \cdot \cos(N\pi/2u)$, and together with the $1/N$ in front of the fraction that makes for a limit of 1.